# how to check in c# if a input string is a binary/hexa. number?

Tags: c#, binary

how can i check in c# if a input string from a input field is a correct binary (or hexa) number?

Comment: You can't in a safe way unless you force the user to prefix it with for example 0x or 0b. Ie 100 is a valid binary or hex, but we can't discriminate. Did I get correctly your question ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using System.Globalization;
bool valid = int.TryParse(inputString, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
```

works for hex numbers without prefix. If you don't know wich number type to expect, you can use

```
bool isHex = inputString.Length > 2 &&
    inputString.Substring(0, 2).ToLowerInvariant() == "0x" &&
    int.TryParse(inputString.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
```

to check and parse the string at the same time. For binary I'd use

```
Regex.IsMatch(inputString, "^[01]+$");
```

You should use `inputString = inputString.Trim()` to make the application more tolerant regarding "non-standard input".

Comment: Props for including the using statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
int dummy;
bool isHex = int.TryParse(str,
                          NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          out dummy);
```

For the binary, there are no built-in functions, but you can use something like following:

```
static bool isbin(string s)
{
    foreach (var c in s)
        if (c != '0' && c != '1')
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Regex.IsMatch("0x6868FC", "\b0x[a-fA-F0-9]+\b");
```

If you expect the user to enter hex number starting with 0x.

Comment: or you could say that the 0x part is optional with (?:0x)?